# How to save/update a model to DB using django?

Tags: python, django

I am using django signals to update a third party service, here is what is happening:

- The signal is triggered whenever `User` is updated
- Get the related model called `account`
- Update the third party service
- Finally, I wantto set a flag in my own DB

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='get_modified_user')
def update_third_party(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    logger.info('signal triggered')
    account = Account.objects.prefetch_related('model2').get(user_id=instance.id)
    if not account:
        logger.info('account not found')
    else:
        syncer = Syncer()
        syncer.update_third_party(account)
        logger.info('save account flag')
        account.is_sent_to_third_party = True
        account.save()
```

The above code runs fine and the third party service gets updated. I see the following output:

```
signal triggered
save account flag
```

But when I check the DB, the value of `is_sent_to_third_party` flag is still `false`

This is how Account looks like:

```
@register_snippet
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='account')

    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_sent_to_third_party = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(
        'schema.table2',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name="accounts",
        related_query_name="account",
        blank=True, null=True,
        db_constraint=False
    )
```

Comment: Can you add the `Account` model to your question

Comment: @IainShelvington: I have added `Account`

Comment: How do you "Check the DB"?

Comment: @BartoszStasiak: I run a SQL query against the DB

Comment: Try with `pre_save` signal instead and remove `save()` at the end of the method. Wait until the whole code finished running and check again.